# Trying to convert Sony MiniDV tape (DCR-TRV19) to iMovie '09. Audio clipping is driving me nuts

Tags: imovie, import

Folks: I'm running Mac OS X (10.7.2) and iMovie'09 on my 27 inch imac. I'm using a Sony dcr-trv19 that is connected via firewire to the camera. The audio, overall, comes in synced (time) fine; however, there is clipping at the higher frequencies that is really annoying. The only way to describe it is that you lose anything above 15hz or so. So every "S" is flat and you get the digitized effect on most words, etc. I've listened to the source tape via the camera in playback to my headphones and do notice that occasionally the camera picked up a bit too much audio, like it is maxed on the level and it hit the red and then digitized. However, that is seldom when compared to the overall level on the iMovie version where the majority of "S"s are cut.  Almost like sibilance effect on the digital side.  There are no apparent audio import controls to bring the level down, when importing, etc. What are my options to try to improve my import qualities?  I've considered upgrading to iMovie '11, but not sure it gives me more import power. Any other tools to import and assess what is going on? Thoughts?